# "No module named math" (and others) error with Docker interpreter, but execution and breakpoints work

Tags: docker, pycharm

I configured Docker interpreter exactly by following PyCharm tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter-1.html, then wait for indexing and skeleton fetching to finish.

I tried executing the file, and even setting a breakpoint. All this worked.

However, the `import math` line shows error `No module named math`. Autocomplete does not work. Even more strange is that *some* built-in libraries import, but some do not.

Built-in libraries which do **not** import: `math`, `json`, `urllib`, `io`, `csv`, `numbers`, `curses`, `logging`.

Built-in libraries which **do** import: `os`, `re`, `time`, `argparse`.

*Note: the import test was not exhaustive*. Other built-in libraries may or may not import.

I'm using PyCharm Professional 2018.1. Version 2017.3 was also tested, and same error appears (tested just `import math`, though). If I use my local Python interpreter, imports and autocomplete work just fine.

I'm using `python:latest` as the Remote Docker interpreter, with `python` as the interpreter path. At this time, this works out to `Python 3.6.5`. If I start the interpreter with `docker run -it python:latest`, and then try to `import math`, everything works:

```
$ docker run -it python:latest
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 31 2018, 01:15:58)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> dir(math)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'gcd', 'hypot', 'inf', 'isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'log2', 'modf', 'nan', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'tau', 'trunc']
```

I have [filed a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29585) with JetBrains, but since this is basic functionality for the feature, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In April 27, JetBrains [confirmed it as a bug with **Docker 18.03.1-ce stable** onwards](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29585).

Suggested workaround is to downgrade Docker to **18.03.0 stable** version.

I suppose manually copying the `.py` sources (in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` inside the container) to a local interpreter path would likely get autocomplete and documentation working as well (although the libraries which depend on non-Python code) would not work.